# Postfix - allow sending e-mail just to authenticated users

Tags: email, debian

I would like to set up postfix in order to send e-mail just if I give a user  and password to my customers. I would like to use debian users (even to track malicious users and suspend them eventually). I've followed postfix guide lines, but even specifying a fake user by sendmail, postfix send it without stopping it. How can I handle this thing?

Comment: Your post isca bit unclear. Are you aware of SASL and if so, what does that not do for you? (SASL ties in authentication before an email can be sent, but it does not prevent changing the senders email address once authenticated, for example)

Comment: The thing is that if I set up SASL, and I use a proper account the authentication system just pass it. That it's fine in an ideal world. The thing is that if a spammer use an "authorized address" it gonna send a mail anyway as an authorized user even if it is not. Now, is there a way to block sending based on a password? Or maybe I've set up the sasl auth in a wrong way. Dunno.

Comment: Sounds like you have set SASL correctly. Not a solution,  but have you looked at policyd/cluebringer? I find that limiting the number of outbound messages/period, in conjunction with monitoring mail queues effective.